# What is the "Online" in Online Transaction Processing or Online Analytical Processing

Tags: database, business-intelligence, olap, oltp

On the web i can find lots of details and documents regarding **OLAP** and **OLTP**, but none of them defines what is the **Online** in *Online Transaction/Analytical Processing*

Comment: The answer from Neil is good, but I just want to point out that it is Transaction rather than Translation, which may help understand what it is for a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Online" as opposed to "Batch"

Instead of submitting a job to be processed at the end of the day and getting a report in the morning, you submit a query and get the results right away